# The x-axis mirroring got screwed up during sculpting, is there any way to fix my topology?

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I must of clicked something wrong. Is there any way for me to re-sync the topology? Dynamic topo is on btw.

Comment: delete half the object and use a mirror modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in *Edit* mode and click on the header menu > *Mesh > Symmetrize*:

[image]

Choose the right axis in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I had no idea Blender can do this :). Still only scratching the surface...

Comment: I don't think anybody knows all the things Blender can do, even maybe Ton Roosendaal   ;)